# How do I update my Firefox in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, browser, upgrade, updates

How do I update my Firefox in Ubuntu.

i.e. I want a newer version

Comment: May I ask what is your version currently? Because if it's already the latest version, we would need to provide you an answer to install a Firefox off the development builds tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to update your Firefox versions outside of the Ubuntu-packaged releases, I'd suggest you use [**ubuntuzilla**](http://ubuntuzilla.sourceforge.net). It'll work not just for this release, but also get future updates for you.

> The Ubuntuzilla project is a python script that allows the user to install the latest versions of Mozilla Firefox, Mozilla SeaMonkey, and Mozilla Thunderbird on Ubuntu Linux. It also works on other Linux distributions that are derivatives of Ubuntu.

Here are a selected list of features, from the ubuntuzilla project page:

```
* Automatically detects and downloads the newest Firefox, Thunderbird, SeaMonkey release from the Mozilla servers
* Allows you to make a choice of language for Firefox or Thunderbird
* Verifies the GPG signature (assures package integrity against malicious tampering or corrupt download) for Firefox or Thunderbird
* Verifies the MD5 sum for SeaMonkey
* Makes a date-stamped back-up of your Firefox, Thunderbird, SeaMonkey profile data
* Automatically integrates Firefox plugins that you have installed from the Ubuntu repositories
* Installs the new Firefox in /opt/firefox, Thunderbird in /opt/thunderbird, SeaMonkey in /opt/seamonkey
* Creates a SeaMonkey menu item in Applications -> Internet menu
* Checks all steps for successful execution
* Has a 'remove' action to remove the official Mozilla build and restore system to pre-installation state.
* Installs an update checker job that periodically performs automatic checks for new versions of Firefox, Thunderbird, or Seamonkey.
* Automatically checks for the latest Ubuntuzilla release and updates itself, to keep up with possible changes in the Mozilla website and release servers.
* Comes conveniently packaged in a .deb for easy installation
* Includes a very helpful man page, for those who don't like to read websites.
```

I moved to using ubuntuzilla around an year back, and haven't feel the need to revert since. Its best feature is that it lets you painlessly install beta versions by manually providing the version you want to upgrade to.

Comment: +1 Useful. I wasn't aware of this project (although I'm aware of problems with using Ubuntu-packaged Firefox).

Comment: great, works nice. Can you please make your answer shorter? A link to the project will suffice

Answer (score 3):

Try the instructions from here it claims it's just a case of doing apt-get install firefox-3.5

http://www.doknowevil.net/2009/08/30/installing-firefox-352-shiretoko-on-ubuntu-using-the-default-repos-and-customizing-the-icon-to-be-more-recognizable/

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu's update manager should take care of Firefox updates.

Answer (score 1):

Is it correct to assume you're on Ubuntu 9.0, using Firefox 3.0, and you want to upgrade to 3.5? If so, then the following page will help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxNewVersion

The easiest solution is to install it alongside version 3 by finding `firefox-3.5` in Synaptic, or running this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox-3.5
```

Then just replace your shortcuts to point to version 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Or you try firefox over [Fabien Tassins PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fta/+archive/ppa)
, add it to your sources.